# gcc Linker error despite specifying -l flag for libusb-1.0

Tags: c, gcc, linker, linker-errors, libusb-1.0

I'm specifying an `-l` flag for my library, so can anyone help me understand why I receive this error for this command?

```
$ gcc `pkg-config --libs --cflags libusb-1.0` sourcefile.c
/tmp/cclBFhzY.o: In function `main':
sourcefile.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `libusb_init'
```

(`pkg-config --libs --cflags libusb-1.0` evaluates to `-I/usr/include/libusb-1.0 -lusb-1.0`.)

I have **verified that `libusb_init` exists** in the library:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.a | grep libusb_init
0000000000001a60 T libusb_init
```

I've furthermore even tried my `gcc` command with an `-L` option:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lusb-1.0 sourcefile.c
```

Still I get the linker error. Do you see anything I'm doing wrong?

*(I've read several other threads on undefined reference errors, but the answers have all been the obvious answer: specify your library in your `gcc` command.)*

Oddly, **I can't tell if gcc is processing my options**. When I run it with the `-v` flag, two salient lines are:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

...which does not include the directory I specified with `-L`. (But it appears that the first entry in the path is equivalent to my dir.) And:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-I' '/usr/include/libusb-1.0' '-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

...which does not include my `-l` option. (Maybe this isn't a valid concern, since the next line does include the `-l` option.) Any thoughts?

*running Ubuntu 16*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `sourcefile.c` before the linker options.

The linker moves through libraries and source files from left to right, noting unresolved symbols as it goes. When it gets to a library (such as `-lusb-1.0`) the linker goes through and resolves any symbols it can find at that moment.

Your libraries aren't being applied to `sourcefile.c`

See also:

[Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)